# Why is my jQuery each loop not adding values correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to get the values of several fields & add them together & in my testing I am having problems. I have this code:

```
var count;

function calculate() {

    // Fix jQuery conflicts
    jQuery.noConflict();

    count = 0;

    jQuery('.calculate').each(function() {

        var currentElement = jQuery(this);

        var value = currentElement.val();

        var count = count + value;

        alert(count);

    });

}
```

I enter in the value of "9" in my first field & when the first alert triggers I get "undefined9"; all the other values are currently set to "0"; when it triggers again I always get "undefined0".

Why am I getting the "undefined" bit & why is it only returning the value of the current field & not adding them together?

Comment: you're probably getting scope conflicts at `var count = count + value;` which is declaring `count` (so it's `undefined`) and then concatenating it with `value`. so yeah, change the names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are dimensioning the `count` value inside the loop, essentially setting it to `undefined` first in each iteration.

You want to remove the `var` within the loop. This way, it doesn't have scope to the anonymous function and JavaScript will look at the parent function for its declaration.

It may also be a good idea to `parseInt(count, 10)` the number first, because JavaScript overloads the `+` operator to mean arithmetic addition and string concatenation, and you wouldn't want `count` to be `"0something"`.

Finally, `count += value` is easier to read :)

Comment: Thanks very much. I removed the redeclaration of it & the undefined is now gone, but yeah.. it's concatenating it the wrong way as a string & not an int. Not sure where you mean where to put the parseInt() bit. Also thanks for the last tip.. wasn't sure how to do that with JS haha

Comment: @Brett: `val()` is returning string values, not numbers. `parseInt()` takes a string and parses it into an integer; Your line would change to: `count += parseInt(value, 10);`

Answer (score 5):

You're accidentally re-declaring `count`:

```
var count = count + value;
```

should be:

```
count = count + value;
```

The count declared in the inner-most scope (that of `calculate`) will hide the other one (this is called "shadowing" of variables).

The reason you get "undefined9" is because the default value of the newly-declared `count` variable is `undefined`; when you add to it, it sees an `undefined` value on the left, and a number on the right, and decides that string concatenation is the best way to perform the addition, resulting in the string "undefined9".

It has to guess at your intended meaning since `+` is overloaded to mean both numerical addition and string concatenation; in this case, it guesses wrong.

Comment: @alex: Thanks. +1 to your answer because of `parseInt`, which I totally didn't realize was necessary here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're defining count in two different scopes - the calculate function, and then in the function that each is using.  You may want to have the second count be named something else, or at least don't redeclare it.